# Finding maximum per row when condition is met

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having the following relatively simple problem. I have two arrays storing `x` and `y` coordinates per timestep, e.g.

```
x = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1]]
y = [[0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.51, 0.52, 0.49, 0.53]]
```

in which 2 timesteps are represented (2 rows). What I would like is to find the maximum `y` coordinate per row when the condition `x >= 1 and x <= 2.5` is met.

How can I define a function which returns an array of 2 columns with just the `max(y)` per row when the spatial x condition is met?

I've tried `np.where` without luck. The result the function should return is:

```
[0.5, 0.52]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use numpy's mask function. The mask function 'masks' the true values, so the conditions are flipped.

```
import numpy as np

x = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1]]
y = [[0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.51, 0.52, 0.49, 0.53]]

x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)

y_masked = np.ma.masked_where((x>2.5) | (x<1), y)
result = np.max(y_masked, axis = 1)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very pretty, but using pure Python (no `numpy`) you could combine `zip`, `filter`, and `max`:

```
>>> x = [[0,1,2,3],[0.1,1.1,2.1,3.1]]
>>> y = [[0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5],[0.51,0.52,0.49,0.53]]
>>> [max(filter(lambda t: 1.0 <= t[0] <= 2.5, zip(rx, ry)), key=lambda t: t[1])[1]
...  for rx, ry in zip(x, y)]
...
[0.5, 0.52]
```

Or a bit shorter, using a list comprehension to filter and reverse order of the tuple so `max` can use natural ordering:

```
>>> [max((y, x) for (x, y) in zip(rx, ry) if 1.0 <= x <= 2.5)[0]
...  for rx, ry  in zip(x, y)]
...
[0.5, 0.52]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you were suggesting a Numpy solution:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3], [0.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1]])
y = np.array([[0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.51, 0.52, 0.49, 0.53]])

print([np.max(y[i][(x[i] >= 1) & (x[i] <= 2.5)]) for i in range(len(x))])
```

gives

```
[0.5, 0.52]
```